# python working with JSON for vis.js timeline

Tags: python, json, linux, python-2.7

I'm trying to setup a test script to find out how to work with python to generate and read JSON.

I want to start with something simple, when pressing a button generate and event for id 1 when release add and end to that event. at the bottom of the script there is an example of the JSON i need to send to the vis.js timeline... id also like to read the JSON file from python to see what is the last id and add from there, maybe some decision making if i need to create a new event or add at the end of that depending on the time between press and release.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime
import json
import os.path

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)


datain = {}
dataout = {}


if os.path.isfile("/home/pi/data.json"):
    with open('data.json', 'r') as outfile:
        datain = json.load(outfile)


while True:


    GPIO.wait_for_edge(23, GPIO.RISING)
    print("Button 1 Pressed")
    print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'))

    dataout ['id'] = "1"
    dataout ['content'] = "Button Pressed"
    dataout ['start'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')

    GPIO.wait_for_edge(23, GPIO.FALLING)
    print("Button 1 Released")
    print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'))

    dataout ["end"] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')

    with open('data.json', 'ab+') as outfile:
        json.dump(dataout, outfile, sort_keys=False)


GPIO.cleanup()

#{
#id: 1,
#    content: 'First event',
#    start: '2014-08-01'
#}, {
#    id: 2,
#    content: 'Pi and Mash',
#    start: '2014-08-08'}
```

**EDIT:**

turns out I was generating JSON wrongly it wasn's a validated JSON file, I fixed it, the issue now is that I can add/append attributes to the object how would i add new event? ...

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import datetime
import json
import os.path

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)


datain = {}
dataout = {}


if os.path.isfile("/home/pi/data.json"):
    with open('data.json', 'r') as outfile:
        datain = json.load(outfile)


while True:


    GPIO.wait_for_edge(23, GPIO.RISING)
    print("Button 1 Pressed")
    print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'))



    dataout = {"Events":[{"content": "Button Pressed", "start": datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'), "id": "1" }]}


    GPIO.wait_for_edge(23, GPIO.FALLING)
    print("Button 1 Released")
    print(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'))



    dataout.append({"end"})
    data[0]['end'] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')

    with open('data.json', 'ab+') as outfile:
        json.dump(dataout, outfile, sort_keys=False, indent=4)


GPIO.cleanup()
```

**UPDATE:**

I've managed to do the above:

```
#dataout.append({"end"})
dataout["Events"][0]["end"] = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```

**UPDATE2*

I have also noticed that this code creates add the new object (new + old) as a duplicated root...

the solution was to open the dump file with a rewrite method.

```
with open('data.json', 'wb+') as outfile:
            json.dump(dataout, outfile, sort_keys=False, indent=4)
```

Comment: If you've answered your questions, you may answer them below instead of updating the original post.

Comment: thanks, havent answered my question yet completly... I will when I have.

Comment: What do you have left unanswered?

Comment: actually making it work with vis.js

Comment: Sounds like a Javascript problem. You may want to post a new question about that